# Container dieing when trying to run a Docker image with Digital Ocean and Rancher

Tags: docker

I am new to Docker. I am trying to follow [this example:](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-multi-node-deployments-with-rancher-2-1-kubernetes-and-docker-machine-on-ubuntu-18-04.)

Early on, when I do a `docker ps`, the status says that it is restarting over and over again.

1. Create a Docker "droplet" on Digital Ocean
2. Perform this command: `docker run -d --restart=unless-stopped -p 80:80 -p 443:443 -v /host/rancher:/var/lib/rancher rancher/rancher --acme-domain nanotwitter.com`
3. docker ps displays this, continually: `416bf4317138   rancher/rancher   "entrypoint.sh --acm…"   8 minutes ago   Restarting (1) 48 seconds ago             focused_buck`
4. The docker event output says that the container died:

   `2022-06-19T15:17:16.162344204Z container die 416bf4317138499ec52684f3c744555b4c0bd1bb0b923664a14e920ccab6f7fe (com.suse.eula=sle-bci, com.suse.image-type=sle-bci, com.suse.lifecycle-url=https://www.suse.com/lifecycle, com.suse.release-stage=released, com.suse.sle.base.created=2022-05-10T14:29:00.558310205Z, com.suse.sle.base.description=Image for containers based on SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 15 SP3., com.suse.sle.base.disturl=obs://build.suse.de/SUSE:SLE-15-SP3:Update:CR/images/ba5146d67e172d2a4c3541b3b996cf08-sles15-image, com.suse.sle.base.eula=sle-bci, com.suse.sle.base.image-type=sle-bci, com.suse.sle.base.lifecycle-url=https://www.suse.com/lifecycle, com.suse.sle.base.reference=registry.suse.com/suse/sle15:15.3.17.14.10, com.suse.sle.base.release-stage=released, com.suse.sle.base.source=https://sources.suse.com/SUSE:SLE-15-SP3:Update:CR/sles15-image/ba5146d67e172d2a4c3541b3b996cf08/, com.suse.sle.base.supportlevel=l3, com.suse.sle.base.title=SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 15 SP3 Base Container Image, com.suse.sle.base.url=https://www.suse.com/products/server/, com.suse.sle.base.vendor=SUSE LLC, com.suse.sle.base.version=15.3.17.14.10, com.suse.supportlevel=l3, exitCode=1, image=rancher/rancher, name=focused_buck, org.openbuildservice.disturl=obs://build.suse.de/SUSE:SLE-15-SP3:Update:CR/images/ba5146d67e172d2a4c3541b3b996cf08-sles15-image, org.opencontainers.image.created=2022-05-12T21:37:13Z, org.opencontainers.image.description=Image for containers based on SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 15 SP3., org.opencontainers.image.revision=c4d59fa88e2313e1446ba542a21c39e15a17f375, org.opencontainers.image.source=https://github.com/rancher/rancher.git, org.opencontainers.image.title=SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 15 SP3 Base Container Image, org.opencontainers.image.url=https://github.com/rancher/rancher, org.opencontainers.image.vendor=SUSE LLC, org.opencontainers.image.version=15.3.17.14.10, org.opensuse.reference=registry.suse.com/suse/sle15:15.3.17.14.10)`

What is going wrong?

Comment: The quick-start guide says that the container should be `--privileged`. Have you tried that? https://rancher.com/quick-start

Comment: That seems to help. Weird that it's not in the example I am using. Maybe they used an earlier version which didn't need --privileged!